# String resources are removed after build

Tags: android, localization

I have a project with following locale values directory:

- values
- values-en-rHK
- values-en-rTH

values and values-en-rHK contains:

```
<string name="currency">$</string>
```

values-en-rTH contains:

```
<string name="currency">฿</string>
```

After the APK is compiled, it removed the currency key from the values-en-rHK directory. I have verified this by decompiling the APK and looking into the resources.

This causes the app to show ฿, even when the locale is en-HK. Also noticed that all the strings with same text as in values were removed from values-en-rHK in the compiled APK.

Answer (score 0):

Your localized directories are not named correctly. They should follow the pattern specified [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs):

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

I'm not entirely sure what you were attempting, the following could possibly work:

- values
- values-b+en+HK
- values-b+en+TH

Values that are identical in different localization versions may be removed when compiling the APK, since there is no point to have the same value in multiple resources.

Comment: How can I name the directory if I have different translations for en-HK, en-TH, zh-HK and th-TH?

Comment: By following the pattern that I have in the answer: `values-b+zh+HK` for example.

Comment: I tried changing the directory names into that format, but the whole `values-b+en+HK` directory still gets removed after compiling the APK (the app still shows ฿). Any ideas?